# uncommit up to before merge

Tags: bazaar

When I have a history

-rev 100, merge 
-- rev 95.3 
-- rev 95.2 
-- rev 95.1 
-rev 99
-rev 98

and I try `bzr uncommit -r 95.3..` it writes an error message. How can I fix the problem?

Error is

```
bzr: ERROR: exceptions.TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'int'

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/bzrlib/commands.py", line 846, in run_bzr_catch_errors
    return run_bzr(argv)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/bzrlib/commands.py", line 797, in run_bzr
    ret = run(*run_argv)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/bzrlib/commands.py", line 499, in run_argv_aliases
    return self.run(**all_cmd_args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/bzrlib/builtins.py", line 3694, in run
local=local)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/bzrlib/builtins.py", line 3717, in _run
revno = revision[0].in_history(b).revno + 1
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'int'

bzr 1.5 on python 2.5.2 (linux2)
arguments: ['/usr/bin/bzr', 'uncommit', '-r', '11955.2.32..']
encoding: 'UTF-8', fsenc: 'UTF-8', lang: 'pl_PL.UTF-8'
plugins:
  bzrtools             /usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/bzrlib/plugins/bzrtools [1.5.0]
  gtk                  /usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/bzrlib/plugins/gtk [0.94.0]
  interactive          /home/adi/.bazaar/plugins/interactive [1.2.0]
  launchpad            /usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/bzrlib/plugins/launchpad [unknown]
  rebase               /home/adi/.bazaar/plugins/rebase [0.3.0]
*** Bazaar has encountered an internal error.
    Please report a bug at https://bugs.launchpad.net/bzr/+filebug
    including this traceback, and a description of what you
    were doing when the error occurred.
```

Comment: 95.3 is not the correct revision number, I think it should be 95.1.3

Answer (score 0):

This is really just a guess, but I suspect that the revision spec isn't accepting 95.3 as a revision.

The merge will have been committed to your branch as revision 100, so you should be able to just do:

```
bzr uncommit
```

or:

```
bzr uncommit -r 100
```

If you want to merge in changes 95.1 and 95.2 (part of the original merge), you will probably have to do:

```
bzr uncommit -r 100
bzr merge -r 95..97 /path/to/merge/source
```

or something like that.

If you need to refer to the 95.3, I'd recommend having a read of the [Bazaar revision spec documentation](http://wiki.bazaar-vcs.org/BzrRevisionSpec) to see if that helps.  You may need a more explicit revision number such as `revno:95.3` (which probably won't work) or `revno:97:/path/to/merge/source` (which might work).  Most of that was a guess though...

Answer (score 0):

You can't uncommit to dotted revision like 95.1.3, because this revision is not in your mainline history. You can use `pull` command instead to get your tree to desired revision:

```
bzr pull . -r95.1.3 --overwrite
```

The main difference between `uncommit` and `pull` is: `uncommit` leaves changes after revision to which you uncommit in the working tree, while `pull` simply overwrite your working tree with files of specified revision.

Also if you need to uncommit to the state just before merge you need to use `bzr uncommit` without specifying revisions if r100 is the last revision in the branch.